# What does { get } stand for in the Swift iOS documentation?

Tags: swift

A question for the kiddie pool:

What does `{ get }` stand for in the Swift iOS documentation?

For instance, in the IndexPath length documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSIndexPath/length) I don't understand the meaning of  `{ get }` . I've seen that in a few other places and am lost as to what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ get }` indicates that only the `getter` is defined for the property. This means that the property is **readonly**.

`{get set}` indicates that both the `getter` and `setter` are defined for the property. We can read as well as write to the property.